# How to iterate through edges in a graph if they are not in a pre-selected list

Tags: python, networkx

I am filtering a subset of edges so I can iterate through them. In this case, I am excluding the "end edges", which are the final edges along a chain:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
end_nodes = [n for n in graph.nodes if nx.degree(graph, n) == 1]
end_edges = graph.edges(end_nodes)
print(f"end edges: {end_edges}")
for edge in graph.edges:
    if edge not in end_edges:
        print(f"edge {edge} is not an end edge.")
    else:
        print(f"edge {edge} is an end edge.")
```

However, when you run this code, you get the following output:

```
end edges: [(0, 1), (4, 3)]
edge (0, 1) is an end edge.
edge (1, 2) is an end edge.
edge (2, 3) is an end edge.
edge (3, 4) is an end edge.
```

Edges `(1, 2)` and `(2, 3)` are not in `end_edges`, yet it returns `False` when the conditional `edge not in end_edges` is checked (seeming to imply that it is in fact included, when it seems to not be).

What is going on, and how can I filter this properly?

Python version is 3.7, NetworkX is 2.4.

Comment: Either  I am missing something fundamental, or this is a bug in the _contains_ implementation of the `edges` data structure. (Iteration seems to work, kind of, as seen below.)

Comment: I agree this looks like a bug.  I've reported it: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert end_nodes to a set of edges and keep the edges unordered.

```
>>> graph = nx.Graph()
>>> graph.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
>>> end_nodes = [n for n in graph.nodes if nx.degree(graph, n) == 1]
>>> end_edges = set(map(frozenset, graph.edges(end_nodes)))
>>> end_edges
{frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({0, 1})}
>>> for edge in graph.edges:
...     print(edge, frozenset(edge) in end_edges)
... 
(0, 1) True
(1, 2) False
(2, 3) False
(3, 4) True
```

Comment: The developers have confirmed that this problem is the result of a bug in NetworkX (https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3819) but this is currently the most elegant/efficient workaround, I think.

Comment: It appears this is fixed now.  https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3819

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
end_nodes = [n for n in graph.nodes if nx.degree(graph, n) == 1]
end_edges = graph.edges(end_nodes)
print(f"end edges: {end_edges}")
for edge in graph.edges:
    if edge not in list(end_edges):
        print(f"edge {edge} is not an end edge.")
    else:
        print(f"edge {edge} is an end edge.")
```

This should return what you ask for.

Comment: AFAICS, this falsely omits the last edge. (As does wrapping both the returned `edges` values in lists.)

Comment: @Hans Yes, it does. If I change the conditional to `if edge not in list(end_edges) and (edge[1], edge[0]) not in list(end_edges):` then it does give the desired result, but this feels like a roundabout solution to something that probably has a proper solution in the library itself, which I am probably missing.

Comment: Interesting, this might be a second issue in the library :) A `end_edges = [e for e in graph.edges(end_nodes)] ; print(end_edges)` shows both edges, but the last one is `(4,3)` instead of `(3,4)`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but the solution will do till you find the way to do it properly :) Sorry mate

Comment: @Hans It is an undirected graph so I think that that is tolerable - however it is an issue if testing for `(3, 4)` returns false if `(4, 3)` is indeed included.

Comment: This code will be more efficient if the conversion to a list occurs in this line `end_edges = list(graph.edges(end_nodes))`.   Otherwise it converts it to a list every single time through the loop.  It'll be even better if it converts it to a set rather than a list (since searching whether something is in a set is quick).